# Vaadin 10+, How to trigger UI.getCurrent().access in kaributesting

Tags: kotlin, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin10

I want to test a Vaadin flow Component with karibu-testing. In this component I'm using `UI.getCurrent().access {}` to update this component but when running the test the code inside `access` won't be executed. The same result when I try to use `UI.getCurrent().access {}` in the test itself... Some ideas?

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.mvysny.kaributesting</groupId>
   <artifactId>karibu-testing-v10</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

test (Kotlin)

```
class MyUITest {

    @BeforeAll
    fun init() {
        MockVaadin.setup()
    }

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        UI.getCurrent().removeAll()
    }

    @Test
    fun testSometing() {
        UI.getCurrent().access {
            print("foo") // this line is not reachable
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I didn't misunderstand your question. I tried to create a minimal example with a component that is using `UI.getCurrent().access {}` to change something in the UI.

Here I have a component with a single TextField in it with a value "hallo". There is a method inside that component which changes the TextField's value to "hey".

The component looks like

```
package com.example.test;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Component;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Tag;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.UI;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.Command;

@Tag(value = "myComponent")
public class MyComponent extends Component {
    private TextField textField = new TextField();

    public MyComponent() {
        textField.setValue("hallo");
    }

    public void changeValueToHey() {
        UI.getCurrent().access((Command) () -> {
            textField.setValue("hey");
        });
    }

    public String getTextFieldValue() {
        return textField.getValue();
    }
}
```

And then I created a karibu test (v. 1.1.6) like:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    MyComponent myComponent = new MyComponent();
    UI.getCurrent().add(myComponent);
    assertEquals("hallo", myComponent.getTextFieldValue());
    MockVaadin.INSTANCE.runUIQueue(true);
    myComponent.changeValueToHey();
    MockVaadin.INSTANCE.runUIQueue(true);
    assertEquals("hey", myComponent.getTextFieldValue());
}
```

I found those `runUIQueue` in the documentation (https://github.com/mvysny/karibu-testing/tree/master/karibu-testing-v10) where it is said:

> The thing is that Karibu Testing runs the test with the UI lock held.
>   That simplifies testing very much, but that also prevents async
>   updates by another thread, simply because the test is holding the
>   lock!
>
> The solution is to briefly let loose of the UI lock in the testing
>   thread, allowing UI.access() tasks posted from a background thread to
>   be processed. Then the testing thread will re-obtain the lock and
>   continue testing.